# Difference between "striezen" and "triezen"

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between "striezen" and "triezen"?
Duden shows a similar meaning for both.

Comment: Never heard "striezen", so it's very probably a regional word. Yes, the internet says it's from the northern parts of Germany.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you have any quote (and source) where it is used? Because it does sound that you found one or both somewhere and looked it up and got no clue about the difference. So context would help.

Comment: @mic striezen has two meanings. Only one of them is colloquial in northern Germany ([see DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=DWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=34577186&firsthit=0&textpattern=tann&lemmapattern=&patternlist=T:tann&lemid=GS52332#XGS52332()), but I think Duden says it, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **striezen**
  This word doesn't exist in standard German. It is a colloquial word used only in northern parts of Germany. It means *to irritate/plague/torture someone* but also *to steal something*
- **triezen**
  This word also is a colloquial word (so you won't find it in newspapers), but it is used in southern parts of the German sprachraum. (I live in Austria, and here this word is well known.) I have no idea if it is known in northern parts too. It only means *to irritate/plague/torture someone.* It has not the meaning of stealing.